# Creation of a custom board

Tags: azure-devops, kanban

I want to create a custom kanban board based on a new query for my team.

The ones you get by default seem to be an all or nothing thing, we would like to break down our work outside of sprint planning in to "feature boards" that contain items that may span multiple sprints but are towards a common sub goal of our project.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the common scenario which TFS/Azure-Devops designed for.

Based on your requirement, you can try creating multiple teams and areas. Area paths allow you to group work items by team, product, or feature area. Then set team default to select the areas the specific team owns below. The selected area paths will determine what shows up on your team's backlog/board and what work items your team is responsible for.

Please see below articles for more information:

- [Kanban basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/kanban-basics?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav)
- [Set team defaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-team-defaults?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav)
- [About area and iteration paths (aka sprints)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/about-areas-iterations?view=vsts)

Besides, you can also try this extension: [Kanban Board Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alm-devops-rangers.KanbanBoardTools), it provides a set of tools to enhance Kanban board usage within TFS and VSTS.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this free extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=realdolmen.querybasedboards, that allows you to display a query result into columns, based on work item states configuration.